# Need to set Angular2 canvas to fill the parent element

Tags: angular, canvas, ionic-framework

I'm writing an app using the [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/), and I want to make a canvas that fills the content area. To illustrate, I'd like for my canvas to fill the blue content box shown below:

[image]

**My container template**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Compose</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <note-canvas padding></note-canvas>

</ion-content>
```

**And here's the component + template for the NoteCanvas:**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'note-canvas',
    template: `
    <canvas layout-fill #noteCanvas
    [attr.width]='x'
    [attr.height]='y'
    [class]='sc'>
    </canvas>
    `
})


export class NoteCanvas {
    private x: number;
    private y: number;
    private sc: String = 'fixed-content'

    @ViewChild("noteCanvas") noteCanvas: ElementRef;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.draw()
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        
        let canvas = this.noteCanvas.nativeElement

        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
       
        for (var i = -2; i < 3; i++) {
            var y = (500 / 2) + (i * 75)
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
            ctx.moveTo(0, y)
            ctx.lineTo(500, y)
            ctx.stroke()
            console.dir(ctx)
        }

        
    }

    draw() {
        console.log(this.noteCanvas.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode)
        this.x = this.noteCanvas.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode.clientWidth
        this.y = this.noteCanvas.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode.clientHeight
    }


}
```

With that, I almost get the result I want, but it's always too large, and never accounts for the orange margin. Shown below, you can see that there's a vertical overflow:

[image: Overflow]

Can anybody provide any wisdom? I do have a fuzzy understanding of Angular2, but I can't find much that exactly solves my problem online. I'd be glad to elaborate on anything!

Answer (score 0):

Sigh... I found a really hacky approach that worked:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'note-canvas',
    template: `
    <canvas layout-fill #noteCanvas
    [attr.width]='x'
    [attr.height]='y'
    [class]='sc'>
    </canvas>
    `
})


export class NoteCanvas {
    private x: number;
    private y: number;
    private sc: String = 'fixed-content'

    @ViewChild("noteCanvas") noteCanvas: ElementRef;

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.draw()
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {

        let canvas = this.noteCanvas.nativeElement

        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

        for (var i = -2; i < 3; i++) {
            var y = (500 / 2) + (i * 75)
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.fillStyle = "#000"
            ctx.moveTo(0, y)
            ctx.lineTo(500, y)
            ctx.stroke()
            console.dir(ctx)
        }


    }


    draw() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let p = this.noteCanvas.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode
            this.x = p.clientWidth
            console.log(p.style['margin-top'])
            this.y = p.clientHeight
        }, 0)
    }


}
```

tl;dr: wrap the code that depends on DOM objects to be loaded in a setTimeout of time 0.

Still, if anyone knows a more Angular-ish way, feel free to drop it in.